# Сборка и запуск WPF приложения из консоли

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio, консоль

Вопрос вроде простой, но я так не понял, как сделать: хочу сделать тоже самое, что делается при запуске/сборке приложения из `visual studio`, но только при помощи консоли.

Comment: То есть Вы хотите собрать WPF из консоли? Попробуйте `MSBuild`. Примерно что-то наподобие `MSBuild project.csproj /p:configuration=Release`.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

В сборке WPF-приложения нет ничего особенного: его можно собрать точно так же, как любое приложение .NET, вызовом [MSBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019).

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln
```

Основная сложность, из какого каталога брать MSBuild?

Первый вариант: `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. В этом каталоге MSBuild существует всегда, даже если не установлена Visual Studio (поставляется в составе .NET Framework), но версия позволяет собирать проекты только до C# 5.0.

Второй вариант: из каталога Visual Studio

VS 2017: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<edition>\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

VS 2019: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<edition>\MSBuild\Current\Bin\"`

где `<edition>`- редакция: Community, Professional или Enterpise

В данном случае будет поддерживаться версия языка на уровне используемой версии студии.